# window.open in a function replaces current tab as well as opens new tab

Tags: javascript

I have a funny complication i would like to understand,  if i have window.open as the onclick event of an anchor, a new tab is opened as required. If the onclick calls a function, which in turn does a window.open a new tab is opened, but also the current tab gets the new url as well.

I can demonstrate it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/symeon/AJm9x/3/)   it works ok when you click on the link, wheras [here](http://jsfiddle.net/symeon/AJm9x/) the url is also opened in the results area as well !

Thanks
Symeon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first `case` statement is falling through. You need to add a `break`:

```
switch (t) {
    case 1: 
        window.open(url,"_blank");
        break;
    case 2: 
        window.location = url;
        break;
}
```

Without the `break`, every `case` below the one that was first matched will be executed.

I have added a `break` to the second case too, simply because it's generally considered good practice to always `break` a case. In fact, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) will flag a missing `break` as an error.

Comment: Thanks - i cant believe i did not spot that   doh !!!   I have updated the jsfiddle of course....

Answer (score 2):

In the example that isn't working, you are missing a `break` in the switch statement:

```
function doclick(t, url) {
    switch (t) {
        case 1: window.open(url,"_blank"); break;
        case 2: window.location = url; break;
    }
    return false;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `break;` your `case`s.

Answer (score 0):

only `break;` will give you your required results.